# Can't install packages in Atom

Tags: python, windows, git, atom-editor, hydrogen

Can't install packages such as Hydrogen in Atom, when I try I get this error

```
> zmq@2.15.3 install C:\Users\JORDAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11672-8972-1vrxp0c\node_modules\deuterium\node_modules\jmp\node_modules\zmq
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\JORDAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11672-8972-1vrxp0c\node_modules\deuterium\node_modules\jmp\node_modules\zmq>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Jordan Baron\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.9.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild  ) 

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Jordan Baron\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-    1.9.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Jordan Baron\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.9.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig"         "C:\\Users\\Jordan Baron\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\Jordan Baron\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\JORDAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-11672-8972-    ovgc8u\\package.tgz" "--target=0.37.8" "--arch=ia32"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! zmq@2.15.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.15.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am on Windows 10 64-bit, and I have Python 2.7 and the latest Visual Studio version and Git. I have already tried installing Python 3.5 but that doesn't work. I also have node installed.

Comment: Check this one - https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/13

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved this by typing `apm install hydrogen` in the command line. It's strange though that by the command line it can install and by the Install button it can't.

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by temporarily turning off Antivirus protection.